# Как получить сессию куки с помощью requests?

Tags: python, cookie, requests

Каким образом можно получить cookie сессию  с помощью библиотеки requests?Нашел код,который по идее должен брать куки сессию,но,к сожалению не берет.

Ожидаемый результат:

```
'cookie': 'ig_did=EF88BCA9-7C9C-425A-B761-44B80EBCB080; mid=YA_E_AAEAAEFMiE-R0pEyMNXsW1R; ig_nrcb=1; fbm_124024574287414=base_domain=.instagram.com; shbid=10127; shbts=1611868374.666616; rur=PRN; urlgen="{\"217.147.163.3\": 21379}:1l5W7n:CJtK5sCPB5C_70388Bpza3BaA5c"; csrftoken=sYXUU7PhPksEthzSSUgY3VsYoSrDMQKj; fbsr_124024574287414=iyzV24fN0wF-xvCQsMzN3GvYVIxIspo-GBJk6kGq1X8.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'
```

Код:

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as session:
    url = "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/"  
    LOGIN = "username" 
    PASSWORD = "password" 
    dann = dict(username = LOGIN, pass = PASSWORD) 
    session.get(url) 
    session.post(url, dann) 
    url2 = "instagram.com/zuck/?__a=1" 
    r = session.get(url2) 

print(r.text)
```

Comment: У вас ведь уже была проблема с этим и я подсказал как решить ее. Добавьте User-Agent браузера. requests пишет в User-Agent такое: `python-requests/2.25.1`, а это многим сайтам может не понравиться. Еще, те куки что приходят от сервера можно или в ответе через `rs.cookies` забрать, или через заголовок `rs.headers['Set-Cookie']`

Answer (score 1):

```
s = requests.Session()
login = s.post(url, data={'login': login, 'password': password})

r = requests.get(url, cookies=s.cookies)
```